# Unable to debug the code on Localhost

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am executing the code on localhost. I am using server database and not a local database.I wanted to debug the code on localhost.

whenever i am executing the code on localhost, it seems that it is taking servers code and gives the result. I tried breakpoints but it is not calling.I dont know what goes wrong.

In the url it shows `datalinks.expolinks.net/Default.aspx.`
I wanted to run it on localhost.

Comment: Please don’t mark text as code. The requirement for code is there for a reason. Read the [help] for more information. There’s also not much we can say. If you make your browser go to a non-local address naturally no code will be run locally. Reason for that is nothing we can explain since we aren’t in control of your environment and can’t see your settings.

Comment: Try going to Project > Properties > Web > Then change IIS Express to Local IIS or so. I've encountered this issue before and that worked for me.

Comment: @chetan, Since this issue has been resolved, would you please share the solution as an answer? So you could mark it as the answer and it would help other community members who get the same issue, and then we could close this case:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do `datalinks.expolinks.net/Default.aspx` this type of url (it seems live url). for testing of you code, if you are able to connect your code with live server, then change your web.config and debug your local code.

There is not other option.

Comment: actually..I have downloaded the code from live for debugging purpose and executing it locally using live server database.When i am trying to debug it,it is taking servers code and gives the result.I used breakpoints but it is not calling.

Comment: After executing locally,it shd show localhost:filename....but it shows datalinks.expolinks.net/Default.aspx(live)

Comment: then you can not debug, because all your c# code is compiled in dll and can't debug as usually we do in Visual studio. Yes, you can decompile your dll by reverse engineering , there are so many tools for this which give you almost actual code. Then you will debug the code.

Comment: i have downloaded and installed dotpeek to decompile the dll..I am using dotpeek for the first time. So which file i have to decompile as there are many files with the .dll extension. There is one file in the Appcode folder which is applicationextension dll...

Comment: dll with your project name, suppose your application name or csproj (c# project) /vbproj (vb project) name is VectorSuite, then you dll name is 'VectorSuite.dll'.  while decomple you need to decompile your aspx /chtml pages.

Comment: my project name is Datalinks but the dll name Datalinks.dll is not there...

Comment: it means you have local code of that dll, I assume this, so just right click on project -> properties -> will open multi tab page, go to Application tab , there are 'Assembly Name' textbox which is refer to your dll name when you build or published

Comment: hi...there is no application tab after clicking on Project->property pages...i am getting References...Build...Accessibility...MSBuildoptions...

Comment: fine, in build or other tab option, assembly textbox of buildname textbox comes, that will be your app name

Comment: @chetan, It seems your app was not the web project, it was the web site project, just view the "Property Window"(not the Property Pages), could you find the property "Opened URL"?

Comment: It was all because of hyperlink. href="http://........" .So when i was clicking on add button in  order to debug , it was redirecting to  server file for execution.i changed that to href="~/abc.aspx" to execute it on localhost for debugging. Thank u so much @ajay for the suggestions...:) Because of this thing,i have learned something new about dll and tools..